# Form Submission, Auto-Email & jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, email

As I am new in programming, I would like to enquire about using html & php simultaneously for form submission.

Basically, the form is made by html, and php is used to automatically send an email to a certain address.

I want to use jquery as well for form validation and for replying with the message: "Thank you for your comment".

However, it seems that I am facing an issue. When I hit "Send", an email is not sent to the9 address I choose, and no message pops up.

I am pretty sure there are errors with the code. Can anyone check and help?

Thanks.

```html
<form id ="myForm" class="myForm" action="submit_student_form.php" method="post">
  <h1 class="form-title">My title</h1>
  <label>Name*</label>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Please put name here" required>
  </p>
    <p>
  <label>Contact*</label>
  <input type='tel' name="telephone" placeholder="00000000 968+" maxlength="13" minlength="12" required>
    </p>
    <p>
   <label>Comment</label>
  <input type="text" name="comment" placeholder="comment here" size="100">
  </p>
    <p>
  <button type="Submit">Send</button><br>
  
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "xxx@gmail.com
";
    $email_subject = "Subject";
    $email_message = "Details Below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name*: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact*: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comment: ".clean_string($comment)."\n";

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);
?>

 <?php
}
?>

<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
 
    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script> 
</head>
```

So, basically what I need is:

1) Email to be sent to the given address automatically in php upon hitting "Send".

2) jquery to respond with "Thank you for your comment" upon hitting "Send".

I would appreciate your help in this.

Comment: Are you using localhost? If so, have you setup the email server ?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am testing directly on my local pc. I want the mail to be automatically sent without the need to open an email client.

Comment: Are you working in windows or linux ?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer is provided considering you have properly setup email server in place.**

Your html code block doesn't have email field which you are checking in your php script in 1st line.

You will either have to add email text input in html code or remove isset block from php code. Personally i would prefer adding email field.

**Solution 1 - Add email input**

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email address here">
```

**Solution 2 - remove isset from php script**

```
<?php
    $email_to = "xxx@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Subject";
    $email_message = "Details Below.\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Name*: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Contact*: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comment: ".clean_string($comment)."\n";

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try thatm but Is the jquery correct?

I am not getting the feedback "Thank you for your comment!" when I hit "Send".

Comment: Hi @Johnanon123 - if my code worked then you may accept the answer.